# How does Azure IoT Edge detect new modules?

Tags: azure, iot

In an Azure IoT Edge solution when a module gets pushed from the cloud to the edge, how does IoT Edge detect it?

Does it entail any change of code to the module that's been pushed to make it work on the edge? I really didn't find sufficient documentation on this. It would be really helpful to throw some examples or provide some links to some enlightening documentation.

Comment: What do you mean of "**a module gets pushed from the cloud to the edge**" ?

Answer (score 1):

See updated news and docs about IoT Edge that has been drastically updated since this original question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-iot-edge-works
In a nutshell, the IoT Edge runtime is configured from IoT Hub and will pull the modules as defined by the configuration, so there is no "discovery" needed on the Edge device.

Comment: Does the configuration information gets pushed to the IoT Edge in real time or the edge needs to keep polling for the updates in the config file? That will answer the original question - how does the edge detect new modules? The link you included doesn’t address that.